# Tengo un problema con el getfolderbyserverrelativeurl en Sharepoint Api Rest js

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint

Tengo un problema me genera este error, lo que pasa es que quiero guardar un archivo en un biblioteca de documento pero me sale estos errores.

> ```
>    //Este es Mi codigo
>     var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
>     var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];
> ```

```
    // Construct the endpoint.
    var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
        "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/upload')/files" +
        "/add(overwrite=true, url='{1}')",
        serverUrl,fileName);

    // Send the request and return the response.
    // This call returns the SharePoint file.
    console.log("File Collection =>", fileCollectionEndpoint);

    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: arrayBuffer,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué contiene la variable serverUrl ?

Comment: Contiene la URL del server en sharepoint                                       
**serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl**

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en el armado de tu ruta relativa:
En la construcción de tu endpoint, así:

Revisa bien esta línea estás llamando a una función/método que por el nombre deduzco: Obtiene la url relativa de la carpeta en el servidor. Y lo estás uniendo a una cadena como parte de la url.

La función `getfolderbyserverrelativeurl` :

```
var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

// Construct the endpoint. 
var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
    "{0}/_api/web/" + getfolderbyserverrelativeurl("/upload") + "/files" +
    "/add(overwrite=true, url='{1}')",
    serverUrl,fileName);

// Send the request and return the response.
// This call returns the SharePoint file.
console.log("File Collection =>", fileCollectionEndpoint);

return jQuery.ajax({
    url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
    type: "POST",
    data: arrayBuffer,
    processData: false,
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
});
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos.

Como referencia te dejo un recurso del sitio de Microsoft que puede ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

[Como cargar un archivo a un sitio SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms454491(v%3Doffice.14))